# color compatability issues in Internet explorer and firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I got stuck among the weared behaviour of browsers. Ihave a div which has a background image which has color code #fbc61e so i set the background color of div to #fbc61e.

This works well in Inernet explorer. But when I render same page on firefox an edge appears between image and background where image ends.

When I analysed the snapshot of firefox page I got the colorcode of image #fece00 and when I set div background to #fece00 then edge disappears in firefox but appears in Internet explorer.

Please enlighten me to resolve this problem.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Are you able to post some of your codes here?

Comment: background image is in .png format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably tripping over embedded color profiles, which IE and FF handle differently. Depending on your graphics editor, you should use something like "Export for Web and Devices" (Photoshop/Illustrator terminology). Set your color profile to sRGB to avoid surprises when exporting.

Answer (score 0):

GIFs and 8-bit PNGs are the only safe choices for what you're trying to do, but you can try getting rid of any gamma tags that might have been written out to your file to see if it helps.